# Relational Database Approach To Save Multiple Genres For A Movie

Tags: sql, database-design

I need an opinion on this database structure, Is this a good way to store the movies?

- Movies Table: All the Movie Names
- Genre Table: All The Genre Names
- Movies Post Table: All the posts related to that table
- Movie Genre Relation: It tells which genre is related to which movie or which movie related to which genre

Movies

```
| id | name |
| - | - |
| 1| Movie1|
| 2| Movie 2|
```

Genres

```
| id | genre|
| - | - |
| 1| Sc-Fi|
| 2| Comedy|
```

Movie Post

```
| id | title| movieID |movieGenre
| - | - |- |- |
| 1| Awesome Movie|1|1,2
| 2| Best Movie|2|2
```

Movie-Genre Relation

```
| id | movieID| genreID
| - | - | -|
| 1| 1|1|
| 2| 1|2|
| 3| 2|2|
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the minor suggestion of putting all the table names in the plural.

Beyond that, the `movieGenre` column in `moviePosts` is redundant.  Normally, the `genre` is related to a single movie, not to a post about the movie.

There are reasons why you might want such a column.  For instance, if the genres changed over time, you might want to capture the genres at the point in time when the post was made.  Summarizing the genres would be one approach to addressing that issue.

However, movie genres do not (normally) change over time.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a little bit let's say the user requested? moviePost :1 which is having 2 genres. I've exploded the 1,2 into an array. Now how do I select genre details using the IDs in most efficient way...

Comment: @Matte . . . You have the genres in the `movieGenres` table.

Comment: "*putting all the table names in the plural*" - I disagree ;) This is highly personal taste. And I think the table name should reflect the name of the entity - which is clearly "movie", not "movies". You don't name classes in Java/C++/PHP in plural either. But I do agree that the same naming convention should be applied to  all names. So either always singular or always plural.